# Authorization for API gateway external requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Currently I have set up an API gateway that external systems will use. What are some good ways which you can handle authorization to the endpoints?

I know API gateway provides keys out of the box but that really doesn't help with the authorization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend considering:

- Cognito Authorizer Lambdas ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html))
- JWT Authorizer Lambdas ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html))
- CORS introduction in API gateway level ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html))

Other forms of protection that might be helpful are:

- Level 7 Protection - AWS WAF ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-aws-waf.html))
- Layer 3 & 4 Protection - AWS Advance Shield ([Link](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/#:%7E:text=With%20AWS%20Shield%20Advanced%2C%20you,mitigate%20sophisticated%20application%20layer%20attacks.))
- Rate Limiting Feature of API Gateway ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html))